# Python inactive screen capture

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

I want to make a screenshot of an inactive window with win32gui.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import win32gui

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Calculator')
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
dimensions = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)

image = ImageGrab.grab(dimensions)
image.show()
```

But it is not working as expected. It grabs a screen region but it does not grab exactly where the window is.  I have also tried resizing the calculator window but it doesn't help. My screen resolution is 1920*1080 if that is relevant.

Screenshot:

[image: Calculator attempt].

Please help me if you have any solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ImageGrab with bbox from pywin32's GetWindowRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786794/using-imagegrab-with-bbox-from-pywin32s-getwindowrect)

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem here is the DPI settings described in [Using ImageGrab with bbox from pywin32's GetWindowRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786794/using-imagegrab-with-bbox-from-pywin32s-getwindowrect), but there will still be extra space around the rectangle returned by `win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)` thanks to a feature of Windows 10 described in [GetWindowRect too small on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192232/getwindowrect-too-small-on-windows-7), which, from what I have read, started appearing with Windows 8 and Aero.

So, for completeness, here is a solution:

```
# imports
import win32gui, win32con, ctypes  
from PIL import ImageGrab
from ctypes import wintypes

# this takes care of the DPI settings (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786794/using-imagegrab-with-bbox-from-pywin32s-getwindowrect)
ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()

# get window handle and dimensions 
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Calculator')
dimensions = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)    

# this gets the window size, comparing it to `dimensions` will show a difference
winsize = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)

# this sets window to front if it is not already
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,0,0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,0,0, win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW | win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)

# grab screen region set in `dimensions`
image = ImageGrab.grab(dimensions)
image.show()

# we're going to use this to get window attributes
f=ctypes.windll.dwmapi.DwmGetWindowAttribute

# `rect` is for the window coordinates
rect = ctypes.wintypes.RECT()
DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS = 9

# and then the coordinates of the window go into `rect`
f(ctypes.wintypes.HWND(hwnd),
  ctypes.wintypes.DWORD(DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS),
  ctypes.byref(rect),
  ctypes.sizeof(rect)
  )

# if we want to work out the window size, for comparison this should be the same as `winsize`
size = (rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top)        

# put the window coordinates in a tuple like that returned earlier by GetWindowRect()
dimensions = (rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom)

# grab screen region set in the revised `dimensions`
image = ImageGrab.grab(dimensions)
image.show()
```

And then `image` should have the correct boundaries.